# DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated since Python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have project using `python3.6` which in I use `pytest` for testing. Everything was working fine but suddenly when I run `py.test` I get this warning message

> =============== warnings summary===========
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gevent/monkey.py:685
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gevent/monkey.py:685:
>   DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated since Python
>   3.0, use inspect.signature() or inspect.getfullargspec()
>       patch_all_args = getargspec(patch_all)[0] # pylint:disable=deprecated-method
>
> -- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html

First of all, I haven't changed anything. And secondly the warning is for `monkey.py` in `python3.6`.

Why should I get this warning in my project and how can I fix this?

Comment: it's telling you that `monkey.py` is using a deprecated method. you can fix this by upgrading `gevent` if possible, or you can update your `pytest` config to ignore `DeprecationWarning`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the [documents](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html#disabling-warning-capture-entirely), I've found out that I have two ways to disable this warning:

1. Passing `-p no:warnings` to the `py.test` in command line:

   ```
   py.test -p no:warnings
   ```
2. Disable only deprecation warnings once and for all by modifying `pytest.ini`:

   ```
   [pytest]

   filterwarnings =
       ignore:.*U.*mode is deprecated:DeprecationWarning
   ```

Comment: Disabling warnings is usually a bad idea - the warnings are there to tell you something important (in this case, that some code you're depending on is due to stop working in a future version). Eliminating the cause of the warning (in this case, by upgrading the dependency that's emitting it) is greatly to be preferred.